# Magento2 Error when clicking configurable product admin panel grid Section

Tags: error, adminhtml, grid, admin-panel, migration

My Question is Magento2 Error when clicking configurable product admin panel grid Section.

"This Product doesn't exit"

So give me solution .

[image]

Thank you,
Your Faithfully,
Mehul Kanjariya